# Concat FC layer with Deconvolutional Layer

Tags: concatenation, layer, caffe, deconvolution

I'm trying to concat a Deconvolution layer with fully connected layer for be processed conlutional layers, but when I do reshape after concat Deconv Layer with FC layer, my batch size change, this is the procees wich I do:

```
......

    layer {
      name: "fc4"
      type: "InnerProduct"
      bottom: "fc3"
      top: "fc4"
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
        decay_mult: 1
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 2
        decay_mult: 0
      }
      inner_product_param {
        num_output: 21904
        weight_filler {
          type: "gaussian"
          std: 0.01
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 0
        }
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "deconv"
      type: "Deconvolution"
      bottom: "data"
      top: "deconv"
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
        decay_mult: 1
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 2
        decay_mult: 0
      }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 256
        pad: 1
        kernel_size: 8
        weight_filler {
          type: "gaussian"
          std: 0.01
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 0
        }
      }
    }
    layer {
      type: "Flatten"
      bottom: "deconv"
      top: "dec_flatten"
      name: "dec_flatten"
    }
    layer {
      name: "concat"
      bottom: "fc4"
      bottom: "dec_flatten"
      top: "concat"
      type: "Concat"
      concat_param {
        axis: 1
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "reshape"
      type: "Reshape"
      bottom: "concat"
      top: "output"
      reshape_param {
        shape {
         dim: -1
         dim: 1
         dim: 148
         dim: 148
        }
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "conv1"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "output"
      top: "conv1"
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
        decay_mult: 1
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 2
        decay_mult: 0
      }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 16
        kernel_size: 5
        stride: 1
        weight_filler {
          type: "gaussian"
          std: 0.01
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 0
        }
      }
    }
    ....
```

On terminal I have this outputs:

```
0428 11:45:41.201318 52048 net.cpp:454] fc4 <- fc3
I0428 11:45:41.201325 52048 net.cpp:411] fc4 -> fc4
I0428 11:45:41.320688 52048 net.cpp:150] Setting up fc4
I0428 11:45:41.320735 52048 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 1 21904 (21904)
I0428 11:45:41.320740 52048 net.cpp:165] Memory required for data: 114240
I0428 11:45:41.320752 52048 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer deconv
I0428 11:45:41.320770 52048 net.cpp:106] Creating Layer deconv
I0428 11:45:41.320776 52048 net.cpp:454] deconv <- data_data_0_split_1
I0428 11:45:41.320786 52048 net.cpp:411] deconv -> deconv
I0428 11:45:41.322069 52048 net.cpp:150] Setting up deconv
I0428 11:45:41.322095 52048 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 1 256 37 37 (350464)
I0428 11:45:41.322100 52048 net.cpp:165] Memory required for data: 1516096
I0428 11:45:41.322110 52048 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer dec_flatten
I0428 11:45:41.322119 52048 net.cpp:106] Creating Layer dec_flatten
I0428 11:45:41.322124 52048 net.cpp:454] dec_flatten <- deconv
I0428 11:45:41.322130 52048 net.cpp:411] dec_flatten -> dec_flatten
I0428 11:45:41.322156 52048 net.cpp:150] Setting up dec_flatten
I0428 11:45:41.322163 52048 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 1 350464 (350464)
I0428 11:45:41.322167 52048 net.cpp:165] Memory required for data: 2917952
I0428 11:45:41.322171 52048 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer concat
I0428 11:45:41.322180 52048 net.cpp:106] Creating Layer concat
I0428 11:45:41.322183 52048 net.cpp:454] concat <- fc4
I0428 11:45:41.322188 52048 net.cpp:454] concat <- dec_flatten
I0428 11:45:41.322194 52048 net.cpp:411] concat -> concat
I0428 11:45:41.322216 52048 net.cpp:150] Setting up concat
I0428 11:45:41.322223 52048 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 1 372368 (372368)
I0428 11:45:41.322227 52048 net.cpp:165] Memory required for data: 4407424
I0428 11:45:41.322232 52048 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer reshape
I0428 11:45:41.322242 52048 net.cpp:106] Creating Layer reshape
I0428 11:45:41.322247 52048 net.cpp:454] reshape <- concat
I0428 11:45:41.322252 52048 net.cpp:411] reshape -> output
I0428 11:45:41.322283 52048 net.cpp:150] Setting up reshape
I0428 11:45:41.322295 52048 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 17 1 148 148 (372368)
I0428 11:45:41.322311 52048 net.cpp:165] Memory required for data: 5896896
I0428 11:45:41.322315 52048 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer conv1
I0428 11:45:41.322325 52048 net.cpp:106] Creating Layer conv1
I0428 11:45:41.322330 52048 net.cpp:454] conv1 <- output
I0428 11:45:41.322337 52048 net.cpp:411] conv1 -> conv1
I0428 11:45:41.323410 52048 net.cpp:150] Setting up conv1
I0428 11:45:41.323438 52048 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 17 16 144 144 (5640192)
```

When I do reshape my batch size changes, they known how reshape without change the batch size?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the `concat` blob is `1x372368`.

Now you were trying to reshape this blob data with the prototxt:

```
  reshape_param {
    shape {
     dim: -1
     dim: 1
     dim: 148
     dim: 148
    }
```

As the dimensions of h=148, w=148, c=1 are already fixed by you, the value of `n` is calculated by `372368/(148*148*1) = 17`

If you do not want to change the batch count, you will have to change the values of h,w or c so that `h*w*c*n = 372368`.

Edit 1:
The answer to your edit:
Right now, your concat layer has a dimension of 207936 per image and you are trying to calculate the loss by using a 1024 dimension label. This wont work as the dimensions of both the bottom blobs are different. You could try connecting an `inner product` layer to the output of `concat` layer with num_output: 1024. The output of this `inner product` layer could then be used in the loss layer along with the label.

Comment: Thanks Anoop, I'll try that.

Comment: Anoop, thinking about that this solution i guess which be change my result, I do a test set the two bottom in loss layer on conv3, that way the training works, but this is wrong?

For clarify which I trying to do I follow this paper:  [link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07235v2.pdf)

Comment: If you mean to say that you try to set the same blob as the two inputs of loss layer, that is completely wrong. The loss will always be zero and the model wont learn anything at all. Changing the prototxt cannot change your result as you are going to train with that model. Could you please elaborate on what you meant.

Comment: Hi  Anoop, I fixed the problem of reshape, but now when create the loss layer, the network says which labels have be the same dimensions of data, but when i create that i use the same dimensions. My input image is 32x32, how the netowork is for reconstruction i estimate the parameters for the outputs be 114x114. the error is:

F0501 08:54:43.178031 14655 euclidean_loss_layer.cpp:12] Check failed: bottom[0]->count(1) == bottom[1]->count(1) (207936 vs. 1024) Input

Comment: Have you tried connecting an inner product layer to the output of concat layer as mentioned in edit 1? That should solve your issues

Comment: I add more one convolution layer on the final of the network with 1 output and change the dimensions of the labels setting up to dimension of the reconstructed image, and the training finally works, but I don't understand how much the dimensions of the labels influences the learning of the the network, can you explain me that? 
I observe which the loss is very high maybe something still wrong?

Comment: The dimension of the top most blob should be the same as that of the labels. Only then can we use any kind of loss layers to find a gradient value which could be used for learning the weights by backpropagating through the model. If you were able to solve your question you could accept this as the answer. Any new doubts could be brought forward as a different question with clear details. Also, the comments section never gives a clear idea of the problem.